How do I find plumbing/electrical in drywall?
I moved into a 2016 cinder block house. It has an attached garage from which the electrical and hot water travel to the rest of the house. The interior walls of the garage are largely finished with drywall.
The previous owner had tried to put Closet Maid uprights along the back wall (drywall) but they aren't well anchored and the attached shelves are not level. It was a really great idea on his part and I'd like to redo the job. I bought two sections of the track/rail that the uprights hook into. I'd like to use ezanchors on the uprights and possibly the track. Perhaps the track can screw directly into studs. Only problem is I have no idea where the pipes and electrical are.
Any advice on tools or techniques?

If the "ezanchors" you have in mind are the product I think they are, they are not the correct anchor for cinder block (CMU) walls (whether they are filled or hollow), in my opinion. BTW can you specify whether the CMUs are hollow or concrete-filled in the areas you are anchoring the units, it will help the community give you a better answer.

Welcome. Please take the [tour].

First try finding the screws which attach the drywall to the stud: take a strong magnet and see where it sticks to the wall. Studs should be safe to drive a screw into (and give the screw a better grip than just drywall), except where plumbing/wiring passes through a stud. To find those, search up/down and sideways from switches, power outlets and any pipes entering/exiting the wall (pipes and wires should run mostly horizontally or vertically) and avoid these zones. Still no guarantee, plumbing and wiring may be in unexpected places, especially in older houses which got renovated.

The electrical (and plumbing) should be far enough behind the surface that 1" screws into the studs would be safe. And ideally they should be covered with protective metal plates where they go thru the studs so you couldn't hit them with a screw if you tried. But knowing and avoiding their locations would still be a good thing.
Some "stud sensor" devices claim to be able to detect wires and/or pipes. That is probably the simplest solution.
Another would be to get a bore scope camera, drill a small easily patched hole between the studs, and actually look around. Overkill for this task, but a fun toy to have in the toolkit.
For massive  overkill: there are devices which essentially use the word or plumbing as an antenna, letting you trace it with a handheld receiver. I've actually used a circuit-breaker finder successfully for this, though that only works for wires that are live; the pro device has its own battery in the transmitter so it doesn't require that, but even used costs about 10x as much.

Thanks Keshlam! What's that device called that treats everything as an antenna? The one that doesn't require wires to be live? I wonder if I can rent one somewhere.

I know it as a cable tracer or tracker. EBay shows cheap versions under that search phrase for around $20 and pro versions up around ten times that, but determining which are worth the money is a separate exercise.
